# Drawing a graph using Eurostat data

Tags: graph, stata

I have this database:

[image: see here]

It has one table for each value of `n_person`, i.e., it has 6 values.

How can I, using Stata, draw a graph like this, or at least a trend graph (one trend for each `n_person` for EU-28)?

[image: see here]

Comment: Your data and graph look like they both came out of Excel. Do you want to do this in Excel or Stata? If Excel, perhaps edit tags accordingly. Note that to do this in Stata, you will have a fair amount of data processing to get it in a Stata ready format. In either case, what have you tried?

Comment: Hi  ander2ed, i want to do it in Stata. I know that it could be a long-lasting data procedure but I have to do. Can you help me? What do you recommend?

Comment: It would seem prudent to first get the data for each n_person into single tab in the Excel book with personid in its own column so that each person/geo is uniquely identified (you could also clean each tab and import into Stata and `append`, but one thing at a time). The idea is to add person_n+1 below person_n, so the data is in one table. Change column names as necessary, and it should be ready for Stata. At that point a Stata related programming question can be addressed.

Comment: I have edited your question to inline the images (add `!` before the image tag) and remove the "thanks in advance", which is considered to [not add anything to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). The question is still very broad and could be improved by you showing what you did so far and where, specifically, you got stuck.

Comment: Thank you,  Benjamin W. As you can see I'm a new entry and I have yet to understand how it works. Anyway, ander2ed you suggest me to work before in Excel and than implement the result in Stata. Right?

Comment: Benjamin W. The problem is that I stopped before I start because I use STATA only recently and even if I consulted manuals I did not find the commands I need.

Comment: I expect it would be easier for you to pre-process your data in Excel if you are largely unfamiliar with Stata. Based on the screenshot it will not be a big job to do manually in Excel. Again, you ultimately will want all data in one table that in some way uniquely identifies Geo, Persons and Year that you can import into Stata to begin working with.

Comment: Thanks ander2ed. I will try to do in this way. In anycase, if you find a Stata procedure please let me know because I have to replicate many tables like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward once you have the data in the appropriate format to use in Stata. I'm also assuming EU-28 refers to member countries of the European Union and that you are only importing data for those Countries.

One approach requires you get your data in a format that resembles the following:

```
clear
input str14 geo float(n_persons y2003 y2004 y2005 y2006)
"EUROPEAN 1" 1   62.8377  55.67838 10.905416   35.7592
"EUROPEAN 1" 2  89.53723  71.52719 64.209915  52.47816
"EUROPEAN 1" 3  48.54506 25.441277  51.37198  62.80811
"France"     1  73.91482 36.291607  45.30386  96.40535
"France"     2   54.1567  37.34917 14.375256 21.987514
"France"     3  8.714808  27.92006  54.03687  33.06909
"Germany"    1  38.40068  83.15063   93.3116  59.52254
"Germany"    2  4.605487  97.11422     86.09  10.07262
"Germany"    3  80.91199  77.67971  66.32325  65.57188
"Italy"      1  41.21684   64.3114   9.55155  1.481899
"Italy"      2  50.49801  38.33295  54.57179  37.95589
"Italy"      3 36.950104  .5723338  72.56517 10.015277
"Ireland"      1  29.08498  87.72233  77.70287  3.073141
"Ireland"      2   41.4847  65.26399  52.67126  83.00031
"Ireland"      3 19.666344  20.33027  31.33509  8.294784
"Greece"       1  97.63668  63.63281 15.918014  91.36884
"Greece"       2 19.696716 36.602695  54.15702  56.83243
"Greece"       3 28.321335  86.37221  .8757827 17.157194
end
```

With the data formatted as above, you can then do:

```
reshape long y, i(geo n_persons) j(year)
reshape wide y, i(geo year) j(n_persons)
rename (y1 y2 y3) (persons1 persons2 persons3)
```

to effectively transpose your data and rename variables so that variables are measures of persons in 1 through n person households (one variable for each household size) and the observations represent Country - year pairs (variable naming convention is up to you).

After that, you can play around with:

```
graph bar persons1 persons2 persons3, over(year) stack
```

to produce the bar graph.

See `help reshape` and `help graph bar` for more.